# Econometric Regression

Tags: regression

I want to estimate the effect of Brexit on unemployment in Northern Ireland. I have data on unemployment for towns on the border between Ireland and Northern Ireland for the period January-June 2016 and for the period January-June 2017. 
I have the data for the county's that are along the border on both sides.

How do I estimate the effect of Brexit on unemployment?

Comment: Thanks for your question. However I fail to see how you could possibly have data for the future.